# Flutter: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am building a desktop app whereby I use Firebase for login. To implement this I am using the firedart package to be able to do it. The login system works perfectly. I would like to switch between the login page and a homepage which I have randomly named FirstPage() depending on the sign in state. So when the user is logged out he is taken to login page and if logged in he is taken to the FirstPage(). Whenever I reload the FirstPage() I get the error "Bad state: Stream has already been listened to."

I have gone through multiple solutions on Stackoverflow as well as GitHub and haven't found anything that works for me. Maybe I am not implementing the solutions properly or there is something I am missing.

The following is my code:

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:ame/screens/firstPage.dart';
import 'package:ame/screens/loginPage.dart';
import 'package:bitsdojo_window/bitsdojo_window.dart';
import 'package:firedart/auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firedart/auth/token_store.dart';
import 'package:firedart/firestore/firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_acrylic/flutter_acrylic.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Window.initialize();
  await Window.setEffect(
    effect: WindowEffect.aero,
    color: const Color.fromARGB(50, 0, 0, 0),
  );

  FirebaseAuth.initialize(
      "AIzaSyBk76lyEHpyDgMot7csMmDiIKnPS_5QiYE", VolatileStore());

  var auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  // auth.signInState.listen((state) => print("Signed ${state ? "in" : "out"}"));

  // var user = await auth.getUser();
  // print(user);

  runApp(const MyApp());
  doWhenWindowReady(() {
    var initialSize = const Size(600, 450);
    // appWindow.size = initialSize;
    appWindow.minSize = initialSize;
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: GoogleFonts.poppins().fontFamily,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
          primary: const Color.fromRGBO(7, 96, 49, 1),
          secondary: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      routes: {
        '/firstPage': (ctx) => const FirstPage(),
        '/loginPage': (ctx) => const LoginPage(),
      },
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.signInState,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data == true) {
            return const FirstPage();
          } else {
            return const LoginPage();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

**LoginPage**

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:ame/widgets/rightWindowBar.dart';
import 'package:firedart/auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  List bottomNavTitles = ["Home", "Tour", "Courses", "Articles", "Blog"];
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<void> login() async {
    await auth.signIn(
        emailController.text.trim(), passwordController.text.trim());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // double deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/login.jpeg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
              children: [
                const RightWindowBar(),
                const Spacer(),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: deviceWidth * 0.35),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset('assets/images/ame.png', scale: 9),
                      TextField(
                        controller: emailController,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.envelopesBulk,
                              size: 15, color: Colors.black),
                          hintText: "Email",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 10.0),
                          fillColor: Color.fromARGB(31, 255, 255, 255),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      TextField(
                        controller: passwordController,
                        obscureText: true,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.lock,
                              size: 15, color: Colors.black),
                          hintText: "Password",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 10.0),
                          fillColor: Color.fromARGB(31, 255, 255, 255),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(),
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                              ),
                              onPressed: login,
                              child: const Text("Login"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**FirstPage**

```
import 'package:ame/widgets/leftWindowBar.dart';
import 'package:ame/widgets/menu_list.dart';
import 'package:ame/widgets/rightWindowBar.dart';
import 'package:firedart/auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          const Expanded(child: MenuLlist()),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
              child: Column(
                children: const [RightWindowBar()],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, as the error says, that `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInState` stream has been listened to more that one time.

`FirebaseAuth.instance.signInState`, under the hood, is a simple [StreamController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamController-class.html)([source code](https://github.com/cachapa/firedart/blob/master/lib/auth/token_provider.dart#L18) of package, see also [broadcast constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamController/StreamController.broadcast.html) of StreamController, and notice the difference). And it can be listened to only once. Intended or unintended, the developer of this package made it this way(so the `signInState` stream can be listened only once).

Okay, but what can you do to solve the problem?

1. You can change your code that way, to listen the stream once. For example, call the `listen()` function in `main`:

```dart
void main() {
  // ...

  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final notifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);
  // Notice that usually it is a good practice to dispose 
  // subscriptions, streams, notifiers etc. when they 
  // are no longer needed, but in this case it does not play a big role
  auth.signInState.listen((state) => notifier.value = state);
  
  // And then you can pass down the tree this notifier whatever way you like
  // E.g. by using provider, or simply pass through constructor:
  runApp(const MyApp(signInNotifier: notifier));
}
```

then, in MyHomePage() you can use this notifier like so:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.signInNotifier});

  @protected
  final ValueNotifier<bool> signInNotifier;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
      valueListenable: signInNotifier,
      builder: (context, signedIn, child) {
        if (signedIn) return const FirstPage();

        return const LoginPage();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

2. By some way make the `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInState` stream to be a broadcast. There are many options. For example, you can open an issue, and ask the author replace `StreamController()` constructor with `StreamController.broadcast()` constructor(or make an option for developers to choose whether to use the default constructor, or broadcast), or you can make a PR, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was clear and concise and it worked. I now see where I was going wrong.